# Editing a Keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios9

In terms of application for iOS coding, how can you manipulate the pre-existing keyboards? I want to change a button on the keyboard (for example, the A button on the English key board) to a custom image and custom output.

So I guess what I'm asking is: if and how you can access a pre-existing keyboard and if you can change the output of one of the keyboard buttons to a custom image which others will see if you send it to them?

Comment: You can't manipulate the standard iOS keyboard no. But you can create a custom keyboard if you want (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. There is no way to alter standard keyboards. You can add toolbars above them (via `inputAccessoryView`), you can't alter the actual keyboard.

You would need to create your own custom keyboard.